# manually updating primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

We are dealing with legacy code that doesn't auto-increment the primary key (see `serial`) so I have to manually do it. What is the correct way to manually update the primary key field on insert. I am getting an error when I do the below

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE pizza (
    id bigint not null,
    price int
)
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO pizza
    (id, price)
VALUES
    (
    (SELECT max(id) from pizza)+1,
    1.75
    )
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get when you're trying to insert with the mentioned SQL statement? I simulated your situation on sql server and it works nicely. Although you will get an exception if your table has no rows. Then you would want to use some fallback for null, for example: 
`INSERT INTO pizza
    (id, price)
VALUES
    (
    (case when (SELECT max(id) from pizza) is null then 1 else (SELECT max(id) from pizza)+1 end),
    1.75
    )`

Comment: That's what it was, a null value. Thank you

Comment: In case the table has no data and the database is not in multiple environments (some other database with same schema might have values), you might want to consider changing the table so that it uses autoincrement (identity) in PK field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `max()+1` to generate a primary key. It's not safe for concurrent inserts and it doesn't really scale well.

Just create a sequence and use that:

```
create sequence pizza_id_seq;
```

Then synchronize it with the current values in the table:

```
select setval('pizza_id_seq', coalesce(max(id),1))
from pizza;
```

Then, instead of changing your INSERT statements to use the dreaded `max() + 1`, just use the sequence:

```
INSERT INTO pizza
  (id, price)
VALUES
  (nextval('pizza_id_seq'), 1.75)
```